# user control html not being included on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to do some clean up of a legacy master page for a site i work on. i'm having an issue where a user control i add to the markup isn't having its html dumped on the page.

in the web.config, i added this line to register the path for the controls:

```
<add tagPrefix="uc" namespace="Site.Controls.Modules" assembly="Site" />
```

in the SiteMain.Master, i added the control like this:

```
...
    <div id="HeaderTop">
        <!-- dynamic insert of header top -->
        <uc:MainHeaderTop ID="homepageHeader" Visible="false" runat="server" />
    </div>
...
```

when i load the main page, i set the homepageHeader.Visible property to true. this code gets hit and runs fine. it looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // _item is the current item for this page.
    if (_item.TemplateName == "Homepage")
        homepageHeader.Visible = true;
    else
        phNotHomepageHeader.Visible = true;
    ... 
}
```

if i set a breakpoint in the code-behind for MainHeaderTop, I hit the breakpoint fine. however - when the page loads, all I get is the empty div wrapping the  tag with no markup inside of it. it looks like this:

```
<div id="HeaderTop"  class="homeHeader">
    <!-- dynamic insert of header top -->
</div>
```

Am I missing something basic I need to do to get this working?

edit:
in the SiteMain.Master OnPreRender event, I placed the following code:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    string markup = string.Empty;
    using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        using (var hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            homepageHeader.RenderControl(hw);
            markup = sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

after this runs, markup is an empty string. here is the markup in MainHeaderTop:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainHeaderTop.ascx.cs" 
        Inherits="Site.Controls.Modules.MainHeaderTop" %>

<a href="http://www.site.com" style="width:100; height=200;">
    <img src="~/media/F7E4164AF46A4B1791FCC60CE99763EC.ashx" alt="site" />
</a>
```

and its code behind: (the statement added just to set a breakpoint)

```
namespace Site.Controls.Modules
{
    public partial class MainHeaderTop : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                int i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when it's not set to Visible false in the markup? And is Page_load hit in the control?

Comment: yes, in the SiteMain.Master Page_Load i do `homepageHeader.Visible = true;`, and homepageHeader is valid and a reference to a MainHeaderTop control.

Comment: Where do you set the visibility to true? Please provide some code.

Comment: added the boiled down page load to the relevant section

Comment: Have you checked the `this.Visible` value in the `PreRender` of the control?

Comment: yes. it is true from the earlier assignment in the Page_Load. the visibility doesn't seem to be the issue. the issue is the control not returning any of the markup from the ascx file.

Comment: This might be a stupid question (apologies if so) but shouldn't you be referencing the control via a `src` attribute to the `.ascx` file in your web.config?

Comment: i added it that way, so that when i type uc: in the markup, i get a list of all user controls in that namespace (we have like 200+ separate user controls for this site). it was my impression that setting it up this way, you could type say <uc:MainHeaderTop>, and asp would work out the path to which control you're talking about?

Comment: It **might** do that, I honestly haven't tried it myself, but my initial thoughts would be that the assembly doesn't necessarily know where the .ascx mark-up is in relation to a class name. I would try adding `<add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MainHeaderTop" Src="~/CorrectPath/MainHeaderTop.ascx" />` and see if that works?

Comment: Sorry, just realised the attributes are case-sensitive, so it should be `src` and not `Src`... `<add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MainHeaderTop" src="~/CorrectPath/MainHeaderTop.ascx" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the testing I've just done, you need to specifically reference the `.ascx` file in your web.config set-up.

ASP.NET needs to know exactly where the mark-up for the control lives, because it cannot just "know" where the file is based on the name of the class you're calling.

By referencing just the namespace / assembly (as you currently have) it looks like it is loading just an instance of the class.  This is working because the class in question in your code is not trying to do anything with any server-controls situated in the .ascx mark-up.

If you did have a server-control, and tried to do something with it, then I think you would find an exception raised because the control "doesn't exist" in this situation.

**So what I believe you need to do is:** place the following for each control you want to register in the web.config (obviously setting the `tagName` and correct `src`)...

```
<add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MainTopHeader" src="~/CorrectPath/MainTopHeader.ascx"/>
```

As you say you have 200+ user controls, you probably just want to register the common ones, and then in the individual pages that need them, use the normal reference...

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="AnotherCtrl" Src="~/CorrectPath/AnotherCtrl.ascx" %>
```

I hope this makes sense

Comment: this actually seems to make perfect sense. let me try this now.

Comment: Great, glad I could help, @Mike. Good luck with the rest of your project :-)  (Hope you don't have to have all 200 references!)

Comment: nope, don't need to include all 200+, just a few to clean up the markup :)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Way using -**

`style="display:none;"` by default

```
<uc:MainHeaderTop ID="homepageHeader" Visible="true" style="display:none;" 
runat="server" />
```

& using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$("#<%=homepageHeader.ClientID %>").css("display", "");
});
```

Comment: this isn't very helpful, considering no html for this control is dumped to the page at all - even though the Page_Load for the control is hit.